# Can multiple different Winston logger instances share the same file transport?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, winston

I have multiple winston loggers (different instances created with `createLogger()`), and I'd like all of them to write their logs to the same file transport. Is it supported? Does winston take care of all the low-level details of (possibly) multiple file handles, overriding of data, etc.?

Comment: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1685